# cannot remove network mapped drive

Tags: networking, hard-drive, mapped-drive, file-server

i'm trying to substitue a windows 2012 R2 fileserver with a 2016, on the clients i'm changing the network mapped drives through a VBS script, here's an example of how it removes the drives:

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set Drives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives

For i = 0 to Drives.Count - 1 step 2
    wshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive Drives.Item(i), true, true
Next
```

problem is: now in my notebook, i see those drives from the older server like offline, but i can access their content entering those directory.
I want to remove them and i can't, i tried using prompt, powershell, VBS and resource explorer, the error is always 'mapped drive inexistent'.

But with powershell, `get-psdrive` does actually find them, `remove-psdrive` cannot use that output to remove them:
`get-psdrive X | remove-psdrive -force`

`net use * /delete` and `net use X: /delete` doens't work, also i cannot reuse those letters to map the newer fileserver (X, Y, Z)

And i emptied this entries in the system register editor

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network
```

but it doesn't work, the cache still repopulates

Comment: Can you in Explorer right-click the drive and select Disconnect? Does it work? In batch you may use `net use Z: /delete` or even `net use * /delete`.

Comment: yeah i also tried those things, always same error 'mapped drive inexistent'

Comment: Can you in Disk Management see these disks? Try to right-click and select "Change Drive Letter and Path" and then click Remove. Question: Do you have PowerISO installed?

Comment: no i don't have PowerISO, yes i see them in disk management but i can't do anything. Anyway it resolved itself, somevay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that with some reboot windows 10 can re-map those drives, i did not understand how and where those information where stored but 2 days later they were green and online.
At that point it was easy to disconnect them and remap to the newer server.

Thanks anyways.